# Can we do a number to number encryption and decryption in javascript/nodejs without converting it to a string value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, encryption

I have a field in mongo which is of number type and I want to encrypt it into a unique number to save it and then decrypt it back to the original number without converting it to a string value.

Comment: You want to save a string as number ? Could you give some reason behind that ? Also , as far as I know, there isn't a popular implementation that gives such result.

Comment: @AnkushVerma Actually I want to encrypt a number value and I want the resulted encrypted value should be a number only so that I can save it in my database as I have declared that value as Number in the schema

Comment: Are you sure this field should be a number? It doesn’t sound like it.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, This field should be number suppose for example the field is age and for any reason i want to encrypt it so, I want that it should be encrypted to a number and then I can save it to the database

Comment: Once it's encrypted the data type in the DB is irrelevant; it's value (and type) is only meaningful once it's decrypted. In any case, it's likely this problem is better solved at the DB level and let it handle conversions.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Buffer object, write a Javascript number to the Buffer (creating a binary set of bytes) and then encrypt the contents of the buffer.  Then, save the encrypted binary data from the buffer in your database.

To decrypt, you can reverse the process by reading the binary from the database into a Buffer, decrypt the buffer and then read the number from it.

You can write a Javascript number to a Buffer with something like:

```
buf.writeDoubleBE(value[, offset])
```

and there's a complementary method for reading a number from the buffer.

---

So, this doesn't have to be converted to a string anywhere, but it is converted to a binary Buffer.

FYI, here's an article on encrypting strings, buffers and streams in nodejs: https://attacomsian.com/blog/nodejs-encrypt-decrypt-data

---

FYI, MongoDB has some built-in encryption options (depending upon what storage engine you're using).  This is more like database-level encryption that protects the whole database on disk rather than encrypting individual fields.  Here's some info on that: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-encryption-at-rest/#std-label-encrypted-storage-engine.

The MongoDB doc also has some info on client-side encrypting of individual fields here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-client-side-encryption/

and here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-explicit-client-side-encryption/

And, apparently the enterprise version of mongodb 4.2 or later has some automatic field level encryption.

Comment: Does the mongodb encryption of a number field give a number value or a string ?.. Can you provide me with some example of such sort ?

Comment: @YashKulshrhestha - The built-in encryption (once appropriately setup and configured) is transparent to you using the database.  You just read and write values to the database as you normally would - it just ends up encrypted on the disk.  In order to open the database, you have to have the appropriate encryption keys.

Comment: @YashKulshrhestha - See mongodb links I added to my question about encryption.  You can read more about it in their doc.